# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gt’: object ‘faststack’ is not exported by 'namespace:fastmap'

Tags: r, gt

I'm getting that error message when running

```
library(gt)
```

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you do a fresh install of `gt`.  Also, please specify the `R` version you are using.  Maybe update R if it is an old version and then install the packages

Answer (score 12):

`install.packages("fastmap")` solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 6):

You probably have an older version of `fastmap`.  Run `update.packages("fastmap")`.

EDITED to add:  A comment said that `update.packages` didn't work, but a new install did.  A possible cause for weird behaviour like this is that you have two R libraries installed:  a user library and a system library.  They can each have different versions of the same package.  `update.packages()` sees the newer one, but the code triggering the error uses the older one.  `.libPaths()` will show the currently visible libraries, e.g. on my Mac I currently see

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library"
```

This is the system library.  If I install a package somewhere else I'll probably see that path listed as well, but not necessarily if I restart R in another session.  This can lead to very confusing behaviour.

One way to get into such a mess is to install some packages while running with admin privileges, and others without.  The admin-installed packages will probably go into the system library, while the user-installed packages will go into a user library.

Comment: Update did not help for me. I re-installed `fastmap`. That solved the problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give  a possible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to reinstall everything - R, and R Studio using the latest updates from CRAN. Then everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem - I solved it by updating all my packages.

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with uninstalling fastmap, then reinstalling it.  Rather than reinstalling everything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).